# How can I read json file from SD Card

Tags: android, json, android-sdcard, android-spinner

I need to read a json file from the SD card and display the data in the spinner. Is there any way to read the data from file in Android and display the contents of that file in spinner?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First read the file from SD card and then parse that file

Step-1
Retrieve the data from file from SD card. see [tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523)

Step-2
Parse the data. See [How to parse JSON String](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/)

**Sample code**

```
try {

            File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
            String jString = null;
            try {
                FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
                MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
                /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
                jString = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
              }
              finally {
                stream.close();
              }


                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString); 



        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: As per the Android docs, it states that getChannel() is expensive memory wise.  Is there a way to do this without using channels?

Comment: Even though the setup for mapped files can be expensive, the overall gain (in speed) compared to stream I/O is significant.

Comment: Does NOT work. Some character is being strange?
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf830null{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;\f1\fnil\fcharset128